# How to use COUNT clause with OVER?

Tags: sql-server-express

I currently a beginner in sql query language and I am currently struggling to get the following query to work:

```
USE test;
GO
SELECT deal_type, price_type, 
    COUNT(deal_type) OVER(PARTITION BY deal_type) AS "Count1"
,COUNT(price_type) OVER(PARTITION BY deal_type) AS "Count2"  
FROM deal_price
WHERE deal_type = "rmbs", "Abs"
GO
```

I am currently getting error ("msg 156")

the desired output would look the like the following below:

```
--deal_type, price_type, count_1
--rmbs, talk, 23
--rmbs, cvr, 40
--abs, talk, 40
```

Any help would be very much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: You have an extra "," after price_type

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I still can not get the query to work to achieve the desired output.  Its currently reading rmbs as invalid.  Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Use Single Quotation instead of double, as in 'rmbs' instead of "rmbs", this is also applicable for the As 'Count1'

Comment: You probably ment `where deal_type in ('rmbs', 'Abs')`

Comment: Thank @Absi, so much for your help.  I would like to seek one more advice from you, if you do not mind me asking.  I would like to add another option within the "WHERE" of this query such as "WHERE deal_type = 'rmbs', 'cmbs'", how can i go about doing so.  Thank you so much for your time and help.

Comment: @user1574185 you can add as many parameters as you wish, example : where deal_type in ('rmbs','Abs','Burger','cmbs') and so on

Comment: @user1574185 if you want to show deal_type that ends with the letters bs just say `WHERE deal_type like 'bs%'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `In-clause` :

```
USE test;
GO
SELECT deal_type, price_type, 
COUNT(deal_type) OVER(PARTITION BY deal_type) AS 'Count1',
COUNT(price_type) OVER(PARTITION BY deal_type) AS 'Count2'  
FROM deal_price
WHERE deal_type in ('rmbs', 'Abs')
GO
```

Comment: dear @Absi, thank you very much for your help. however the output is suddenly being displayed as duplicate lines such as "rmbs, talk, 200,""rmbs, talk, 200", "rmbs, cvr, 30". Instead the output should be as follow: "rmbs, talk, 200", "rmbs, cvr, 30", "Abs, talk, 30," etc.

Comment: @user1574185 do you have duplicate lines in your deal_price table and you want to get distinct values ?

Comment: Apology to be burden, but yeah added the distinct clause in as i have duplicates in the table. Thank you so much for your help @absi.  I really appreciate your time and help.  Thanks a million.